# Add "select-all" option inside a dropdown in Dash

Tags: python, css, drop-down-menu, plotly-dash

I want to add a "select-all" option inside a multi-select dropdown. So, by default, there is the small 'x' on the right to clear all values and I want a similar option to get everything selected both when I clear all the options or when I just delete some of them (with the individual 'x' for every option on the left).

Can anyone please help on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

#### Functionality

A bare bones implementation of a "select all" functionality for a `dcc.Dropdown` can be implemented with a callback like this:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash()

options = [
    {"label": "New York City", "value": "NYC"},
    {"label": "Montreal", "value": "MTL"},
    {"label": "San Francisco", "value": "SF"},
]

app.layout = html.Div(
    id="dropdown-container",
    children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown",
            options=options,
            value=["MTL", "NYC"],
            multi=True,
        ),
        html.Button("SELECT ALL", id="select-all", n_clicks=0),
    ],
)


@app.callback(Output("dropdown", "value"), Input("select-all", "n_clicks"))
def select_all(n_clicks):
    return [option["value"] for option in options]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So the idea of the code above is that every time the `select-all` button is clicked, we take all option values and set the `value` property of the dropdown to the resulting list.

#### Styling

Now we can use some css to make it seem like the button is inside the dropdown. In the css below I will position the button to the left of the 'x':

```
#dropdown-container {
  position: relative;
}

#select-all {
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10.5px);
  right: 50px;
}
```

The idea here is to give the container that holds the dropdown and the button  `position: relative`. This is so we can give `position: absolute` to the button and the absolute positioning of the button will be relative to `dropdown-container`.

For the button styles I set `top` to `50%` minus half of the button height. This is so the button is aligned in the middle vertically like the dropdown 'x' and caret.

Comment: It works as a whole but I was mainly thinking of something like an extra option on the top. So above, "New York", "Montreal", "San Fransisco" to have a "Select All" option cause even though it's working there are some issues in usability. For example when there is only one value selected, the button covers the 'x' and the arrow.

Comment: We don't know what design you have in your head if you don't mention that in the question. The button only seems to cover the 'x' on smaller screen sizes. If you want different behavior on smaller screen sizes you could use a media query.

Comment: Yes you're right sorry I'm quite new at this and my question might was incomplete. So, indeed the dropdown is smaller, not because I'm using a smaller screen but because it is placed in a column with other dropdowns, checklists etc. in order to fit graphs and data in the rest of the page. I'll take a look on media queries.