# Insert Select all in dropdown plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to add select all in the dropdown and update its selection on the graph. below is my code but i dont know how to add select all in it . Also, it would be great if one dropdown is depenedent on other like If i select country-India then it should display state names of India only and then after selecting state particular cities of that only. Help would be much appreciated.

````
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

PatientStatus=pd.read_csv('PatientStatus.csv')
app=dash.Dash(__name__,meta_tags=[{"name":"viewport","content":"width=device-width"}])
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.H3('Patient Count',style={'margin-bottom':'0px','color':'black'}),
            ])
        ],className="create_container1 four columns",id="title"),
    ],id="header",className="row flex-display",style={"margin-bottom":"25px"}),
    
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.P('Select Unit Name', className = 'fix_label', style = {'color': 'black'}),
            dcc.RadioItems(id = 'radio_items',
                           labelStyle = {"display": "inline-block"},
                           value = 'Testing',
                           options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in PatientStatus['UNITNAME'].unique()],
                           style = {'text-align': 'center'}, className = 'dcc_compon'),
    html.P('Select Patient Status:', className = 'fix_label', style = {'color': 'black', 'margin-top': '30px'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(id = 'select_county',
                         multi = False,
                         clearable = True,
                         disabled = False,
                         style = {'display': True},
                         placeholder = 'Patient Status',
                         options =[],className='dcc_compon'),
    html.P('Select Country:', className = 'fix_label', style = {'color': 'black', 'margin-top': '30px'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(id = 'select_country',
                         multi = False,
                         clearable = True,
                         disabled = False,
                         style = {'display': True},
                         placeholder = 'Select Country',
                         options =[],className='dcc_compon'),
             html.P('Select State:', className = 'fix_label', style = {'color': 'black', 'margin-top': '30px'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(id = 'select_state',
                         multi = False,
                         clearable = True,
                         disabled = False,
                         style = {'display': True},
                         placeholder = 'Select State',
                         options =[],className='dcc_compon')],className="create_container2 five columns"),
        
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id="bar_chart",
                     config={"displayModeBar":'hover'}),
        ],className="create_cotainer2 seven columns"),
    ],className="row flex-display"),
],id="maincontainer",style={"display":"flex","flex-direction":"columns"})
@app.callback(
    Output('select_county', 'options'),
    Input('radio_items', 'value'))
def get_county_options(radio_items):
        PatientStatus1 = PatientStatus[PatientStatus['UNITNAME'] == radio_items]
        return [{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in PatientStatus1['PATIENTSTATUS'].unique()]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('select_county', 'value'),
    Input('select_county', 'options'))
def get_county_value(select_county):
        return [k['value'] for k in select_county][0]
    
@app.callback(
    Output('select_country', 'options'),
    Input('radio_items', 'value'))
def get_country_options(radio_items):
        PatientStatus1 = PatientStatus[PatientStatus['UNITNAME'] == radio_items]
        return [{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in PatientStatus1['COUNTRY'].unique()]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('select_country', 'value'),
    Input('select_country', 'options'))
def get_country_value(select_country):
        return [k['value'] for k in select_country][0]
@app.callback(
    Output('select_state', 'options'),
    Input('radio_items', 'value'))
def get_state_options(radio_items):
        PatientStatus1 = PatientStatus[PatientStatus['UNITNAME'] == radio_items]
        return [{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in PatientStatus1['STATENAME'].unique()]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('select_state', 'value'),
    Input('select_state', 'options'))
def get_state_value(select_state):
        return [k['value'] for k in select_state][0]


@app.callback(Output('bar_chart', 'figure'),
              [Input('radio_items', 'value')],
              [Input('select_county', 'value')],
             [Input('select_country','value')],
             [Input('select_state','value')])
def update_graph(radio_items, select_county,select_country,select_state):
        PatientStatus2 = PatientStatus.groupby(['UNITNAME','PATIENTSTATUS','COUNTRY','STATENAME', 'CITYNAME'])['PATIENTCOUNTS'].sum().reset_index()
        PatientStatus3 = PatientStatus2[(PatientStatus2['UNITNAME'] == radio_items) & (PatientStatus2['PATIENTSTATUS'] == select_county) & (PatientStatus2['COUNTRY']==select_country) & (PatientStatus2['STATENAME']==select_state)]
        return {
        'data':[go.Bar(
                    x=PatientStatus3['CITYNAME'],
                    y=PatientStatus3['PATIENTCOUNTS'],
                    text = PatientStatus3['PATIENTCOUNTS'],
                    texttemplate = 'Patient Count: ' + '%{text:.2s}',
                    textposition = 'auto',
                    marker = dict(
                    color = PatientStatus3['PATIENTCOUNTS'],
                    colorscale = 'phase',
                    showscale = False),
 
                  hoverinfo='text',
                  hovertext=
                  '<b>Unit</b>: ' + PatientStatus3['UNITNAME'].astype(str) + '<br>' +
                  '<b>Country</b>: ' + PatientStatus3['COUNTRY'].astype(str) + '<br>' +
                  '<b>State</b>: ' + PatientStatus3['STATENAME'] + '<br>' +
                  '<b>City</b>: ' + PatientStatus3['CITYNAME'].astype(str) + '<br>' +
                  '<b>Patient Count</b>: ' + [f'{x:,.0f}' for x in PatientStatus3['PATIENTCOUNTS']] + '<br>'
        )],
          'layout': go.Layout(
            barmode = 'group',
             plot_bgcolor='#F2F2F2',
             paper_bgcolor='#F2F2F2',
             title={
                'text': 'UNIT (' + (radio_items) + ')' + ' ' + ':' + ' ' + 'Patient Status(' + (select_county) + ') '+' Country('+(select_country)+') '+' State('+ (select_state) +')'
                ,'y': 0.96,
                'x': 0.5,
                'xanchor': 'center',
                'yanchor': 'top'},
             titlefont={
                        'color': 'rgb(50, 50, 50)',
                        'size': 15},
 
             hovermode='x',
 
             xaxis=dict(title='<b>City</b>',
                        color='rgb(50, 50, 50)',
                        showline=True,
                        showgrid=True,
                        linecolor='rgb(50, 50, 50)',
                        linewidth=1,
 
 
                ),
 
             yaxis=dict(title='<b>Patient-counts</b>',
                        color='rgb(50, 50, 50)',
                        showline=False,
                        showgrid=True,
                        linecolor='rgb(50, 50, 50)',
 
                ),
 
            legend = {
                'orientation': 'h',
                'bgcolor': '#F2F2F2',
                'x': 0.5,
                'y': 1.25,
                'xanchor': 'center',
                'yanchor': 'top'},
            font = dict(
                family = "Arial",
                size = 12,
                color = 'rgb(50, 50, 50)'),
 
            uniformtext_mode = 'hide',
            uniformtext_minsize = 15,
 
 
 
                 )       
    }
       
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(host="localhost",debug=True,use_reloader=False,port=90)```
````

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68568365/5094044).

Comment: I tried but i am not able to get the required answer. I am getting error in callback while update graph .

Comment: What does the error say?